# Asynchronous data refresh

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I'd like to know how to do the following.

I have a console application which looks like this:

```
Data data;

while(true)
{
   // use data for calculations

   if (Timer())
   {
      data = RefreshData();
   }
}
```

`Timer()` returns *true* if the time elapsed since the last `RefreshData()` call equals to the time it takes to run `RefreshData()` plus five minutes.

I'd like to run `RefreshData()` with the same periodicity, but asynchronously, meanwhile using current value of data in the while loop and replacing it with the new value upon `RefreshData()` completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `await` instead of waiting synchronously for the `Delay` task. This will help in scheduling the `RefreshData` more efficiently.

```
Task.Run( async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay( desiredInterval );
        RefreshData();
    }
});
```

All that said, you may however want to change the design of your app. Instead of periodically polling to refresh data, you may want to subscribe to your data source's change event, if any. If your data source is a database and you want to cache latest data, until it changes in the database, you may consider using [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) and an appropriate cache policy for expiration.

Comment: more on async-await efficiency: http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Async-Await-StateMachine-in-ILSpy

Comment: and about using it in loops: http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Async-in-loops

Comment: finally, run this code: http://pastebin.com/ufhaM6dd  remember application memory usage in task manager, wait 10 minutes, check it again

Comment: @astef: i think you are blurring line between _efficiency_ and _performance_. Since we already have Task.Delay() I don't think performance is required. Using `Wait()` synchronously blocks the thread and makes it a long running task. This is inefficient for TPL. That answers your first comment.

Comment: Second, blog author is running something in a loop with await, which he wants to happen in parallel. Here, we dont want to call multiple `RefreshData` in parallel. That answers second comment.

Comment: Third, I ran that program and indeed there is memory increase. However, similar memory increase is seen when I run it with `Wait()` as in your answer. Are you saying there is memory leak in async/await mechanism? If so, you should post a question and let us all investigate.

Comment: 1 & 2 - ok, no more talks about performance. 3 - you're right, that might be something with `Console` queue. But can you tell me why my example is less efficient than yours? I disagree with "This is inefficient for TPL". (check out my answer edits)

Comment: How is `Task.Delay` approach better than `Timer`/`ElapsedEventHandler`?

Comment: @astef: discussed in your answer.

Comment: @SergeyKraev: `Task.Delay` is not better than `Timer`. In fact `Task.Delay` internally uses `Timer`. Here, it just makes your code _look_ synchronous and easy to understand. You can use `Timer` directly as well.

Comment: @SergeyKraev: However, if you indeed use `Task.Delay()` please never block on it using `Wait()` - it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @YK1: Do I put calculations on `data` inside your `while` loop before `await` or in a separate loop outside `Task.Run`? Should I lock `data` inside `RefreshData()`?

Comment: @SergeyKraev: `Task.Run` should be only called once. Your calculation while loop will be different - and not inside `Task.Run`. You should lock data both in `RefreshData` and your calculation while loop as well. However, please see my updated suggestions about caching and also see this - http://www.jondavis.net/techblog/post/2010/08/30/Four-Methods-Of-Simple-Caching-In-NET.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I propose you to do a think like this :

```
Timer timer;

public void StartTimer()
{
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    // Set the Interval 
    timer.Interval = 2000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    data = RefreshData();
}
```

It will asynchronously refresh data, with your a specify interval.

Hope it's help

Comment: a small concern: How do you assert that data is not being used when a new value is assigned to it? Thread safety?

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ...

Data data;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task.Delay(5 * 60 * 1000).Wait();
        RefreshData();
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

// use data for calculations
```

Consider using `CancellationToken` for cancelling refreshing data.

Consider locking `data` for thread-safety.

Comment: Using Wait() synchronously blocks the thread and makes it a long running task. This is inefficient for TPL.

Comment: Actually, that is a long-running task. Though, you're right, it must be marked explicitly. I've edited answer

Comment: It is still not efficient even if you mark it that way - though it may not use thread pool thread, it makes the TPL create an extra thread for you and then you are blocking it synchronously.

Comment: "It is still not efficient" - why?

Comment: because - `it makes the TPL create an extra thread for you and then you are blocking it synchronously`

Comment: Are you sure you're avoiding it in your example?

Comment: Not performance - but efficiency. When you use `async/await`, no extra thread is created. `RefreshData()` will be scheduled over existing  TPL threads. And each call of `RefreshData()` could be called on a different thread (on a free CPU) - this helps scheduling more efficiently and also takes advantage of your multi-cores.

Comment: You're right. I need to learn more about all this c#5 tricks. Thanks for the discussion